# Running Python Example Code

Tags: python, anaconda

I apologise if this is too basic for `StackOverflow`, but I am currently running `Anaconda v3.6.4` and I am trying to get the first example code from the ML: A Probabilistic Perspective GitHub to work but I have no idea how.

On the GitHub read-me, it says;

> "You should run the code from the repo root ('pyprobml' directory) using module execution, e.g.
>
> `python -m examples.LMSdemo`

The example I am trying to run is in `examples/mnist1NNdemo.py` in the GitHub directory

I have tried using the `Anaconda Prompt`, Spyder and even rewritten the code but I can't see to get it to run this line / code.

I wish I could provide an example but I am unsure how to even open the code correctly!

If you can share how to get the code to work using Anaconda, then I'd be so grateful - I'm at my wits' end!

---

https://github.com/probml/pyprobml

Comment: did you try running it from windows console (or OSX/Linux terminal) making sure that your starting directory is the checkout location of the repo? What is your error?

Comment: "I can't see to get it to run"... if it's not running it must throw some error. include trace-back in your question.

Comment: I've navigated to the directory (C:\pyprobml-master) in both Windows Command Prompt and Powershell. When running "python -m examples.LMSdemo" they return an error stating: "python is not recognised. I've tried installing Python directly instead of through Anaconda but have the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in the future you would be advised to break your question down into smaller parts. The problem you require an answer to in your question is a different one then your current error (as you mentioned only in the comments to your question) is indicating.

The error you are getting (`python is not recognised`) already has an answer [here][1]. Which I will not repeat here since it does not relate to your question.

Once you've managed to get Python added to your PATH simply navigate to the folder  `C:\pyprobml-master` (assuming this is indeed the checkout location of the repo on your system? - I am assuming based on the comments to the main question) and execute the demo via `python -m examples.mnist1NNdemo`.

As an alternative you could also navigate to `C:\pyprobml-master\examples` and run `python mnist1NNdemo.py`

Comment: the link is not working but here is another link to a solution https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path